# How can i use the markInitialState method?

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, myfaces, composite-component

How can i use the **markInitialState**() method?
I want to save the initial state of my component.

Is markInitialState for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markInitialState` is for the container/context's use as indicated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). Use `saveState(FacesContext ct)` for your needs and `restoreState(FacesContext ctx)` to restore the same object. Cheers